# How to make gdm3 start X installed in a different path (or running X from a personalized path)?

Tags: x11, xorg, gnome3, gdm3

I've built the entire Xserver from git for testing proposes using the [build.sh](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/util/modular/tree/build.sh) provided by freedesktop.org as the easier method to compile all modules against the git tree, and installed under the `/opt/xorg` path. The problem is that I can't find how `gdm` decides from where to load the Xserver and related binaries.

I've read on the [X.org site](http://wiki.x.org/wiki/XorgTesting) the section: 'Actually running the conformance tests', but the scripts/helpers that I could use returns a 404.

Although I know where the Xorg executable is and its links, I'm not sure that will be enough to make everything work as expected, as I want to test the Xserver built and installed in the custom path.

I'm using Debian 7.0 and GDM 3.4.1.

Any other method could be used too?

Comment: Please provide the output for `pstree` on your running X11. Very early in that tree your will see a X11-login-manager. I do not know how this looks like on Debian 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer in 2 words:**
The location of Xserver for GDM is hard-coded at compile time in configure.ac, [line 1199](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gdm/tree/configure.ac#n1199) in X_SERVER variable and can't be configured. So, may be you could play with symlinks, linking `/usr/bin/Xorg` (or, less probably `/usr/bin/X`, see [this](http://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2012/09/msg00002.html)) to your build of Xserver.

**Details:**

I have a Debian 7, too and here's my process tree:

```
 |-gdm3-+-gdm-simple-slav-+-Xorg
 |      |                 |-gdm-session-wor-+-gnome-session-+-bluetooth-apple---{bluetooth-apple}
 |      |                 |                 |               |-evolution-alarm---2*[{evolution-alarm}]
 |      |                 |                 |               |-gdu-notificatio
 |      |                 |                 |               |-gnome-fallback----2*[{gnome-fallback-}]
 |      |                 |                 |               |-gnome-panel-+-gnome-terminal-+-bash
 |      |                 |                 |               |             |                |-bash---vi
 |      |                 |                 |               |             |                |-bash-+-less
 |      |                 |                 |               |             |                |      `-pstree
 |      |                 |                 |               |             |                |-gnome-pty-helpe
 |      |                 |                 |               |             |                `-3*[{gnome-terminal}]
 |      |                 |                 |               |             |-iceweasel-+-plugin-containe-+-4*[gtk-gnash]
 |      |                 |                 |               |             |           |                 `-{plugin-containe}
 |      |                 |                 |               |             |           `-31*[{iceweasel}]
 |      |                 |                 |               |             |-pidgin
 |      |                 |                 |               |             `-3*[{gnome-panel}]
 |      |                 |                 |               |-gnome-screensav---2*[{gnome-screensav}]
 |      |                 |                 |               |-gnome-settings----2*[{gnome-settings-}]
 |      |                 |                 |               |-gnome-sound-app---{gnome-sound-app}
 |      |                 |                 |               |-metacity---3*[{metacity}]
 |      |                 |                 |               |-nm-applet---{nm-applet}
 |      |                 |                 |               |-notification-da---{notification-da}
 |      |                 |                 |               |-polkit-gnome-au---{polkit-gnome-au}
 |      |                 |                 |               |-ssh-agent
 |      |                 |                 |               |-tracker-miner-f---2*[{tracker-miner-f}]
 |      |                 |                 |               |-tracker-store---6*[{tracker-store}]
 |      |                 |                 |               `-3*[{gnome-session}]
 |      |                 |                 `-2*[{gdm-session-wor}]
 |      |                 `-{gdm-simple-slav}
 |      `-{gdm3}
```

So, Xorg is started via gdm-simple-slave. Definitly, `/etc/gdm/Init/Default` has nothing to do with starting Xserver, as it was said [here](https://help.gnome.org/admin/gdm/3.8/configuration.html.en#scripting) and [here](https://help.gnome.org/admin/gdm/3.8/overview.html.en#functionaldesc).

There were some [indications](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=451562), that it's impossible to configure, how X is started from gdm.

I decided to go for source codes, which are pretty well structured. So:

Go to the [source codes](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gdm/tree), there is a [daemon](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gdm/tree/daemon) folder, which contains an [INTERNALS](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gdm/tree/daemon/INTERNALS) file, explaining the structure of code.

There you can read:

> ** GdmServer
>
> A class, used by the slave, that manages running a local X Server.

So, the file we need is https://git.gnome.org/browse/gdm/tree/daemon/gdm-server.c

There are several nested functions, responsible for calling X server and creating its command line arguments.

The function directly responsible for running X server process is [gdm_server_spawn](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gdm/tree/daemon/gdm-server.c#n658), which spawns the X in the [line 694](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gdm/tree/daemon/gdm-server.c#n694) with glib's [g_spawn_async_with_pipes](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/glib/glib-Spawning-Processes.html#g-spawn-async-with-pipes).

So, we're to find out, how its `argv` is formed. Well, in 2 words it's [line 293](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gdm/tree/daemon/gdm-server.c#n293) and we need the value of X_SERVER macro (unless you're using RedHat's systemd instead of sysVinit, but you aren't :)).

Alas, this macro is seemingly formed in configure.ac, [line 1199](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gdm/tree/configure.ac#n1199) and is hard-coded. So, it seems that the best option is to place a symlink to your build of Xserver to one of those locations.

Comment: Seems that I can rebuild the package too and install my own `gdm3` broke version :D, no? I'll start now.

Comment: @Braiam Sure, that's a solution, too. Besides, if you found out anything about Gdm integration with Gnome, could you let me know? :) Cause all the documentation on that point is outdated and refers to gconf, while nowadays gdm3 seems to use dconf and no manual on the new dconf layout of `/usr/share/gdm` is available in docs: https://help.gnome.org/admin/gdm/3.8/configuration.html.en.

Comment: What happens on RedHat?

Comment: @Nils It just uses another macro, SYSTEMD_X_SERVER in the server call https://git.gnome.org/browse/gdm/tree/daemon/gdm-server.c#n287 and in configure.ac: https://git.gnome.org/browse/gdm/tree/configure.ac#n931 to start "systemd-multi-seat-x" "X server wrapper". About multiseat: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/multiseat/ and its support: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2012-February/msg02182.html.

Comment: You did hit the mark, and did not at the same time. GDM3 tries to start Xorg from my personalized path but fails miserably without any error. I've created a diff file that contains the changes to be made to the source (only 2 files, or in case of debian sources, 1) for the people interested. `X_PATH`, `X_SERVER_PATH` and `X_SERVER` are the variable to search for. @Bob you might like to look at `/etc/gdm3/PreSession/Default` and `/etc/gdm3/Init/Default` as they contain some hints of configuration available.

Comment: @Braiam Those locations are for scripts, rather than for normally started applications. So far it seems to me, that auto-started applications are configured in `/usr/share/gdm/greeter/autostart`, which contains .desktop files for them. Still lurking in source code to check that. :)

Answer (score 4):

Since @Bob says there's no runtime configuration option for this and I didn't want to rebuild gdm3 from patched source, I took the following approach.

First, move the real X server aside:

```
sudo dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /usr/bin/Xorg
```

Then drop a new shell script in place of `/usr/bin/Xorg`:

```
#!/bin/sh
test -x /usr/local/bin/Xorg && exec /usr/local/bin/Xorg
exec /usr/bin/Xorg.distrib
```

This script will run `Xorg` from `/usr/local` if there's a version there, or fall back to the Debian-packaged version that we `dpkg-divert`ed in the first step otherwise.

This way you can easily rollback to a known-good version by removing or renaming your custom-built `Xorg` binary; I do that using [GNU Stow](http://www.gnu.org/software/stow/).