# Boot to a terminal by default but still have GUI loading in Debian?

Tags: debian

I've installed Debian on an old netbook of mine which I intend to turn into a thin client for a personal thingie while also having it ready to play a video or some music when needed.
After swimming against the current for hours, working around [known bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/925760/comments/8) and [getting wireless to work](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#Ubuntu.2FDebian), I've finally come to a point where I can't find any more help on Google. (I've hardly used Linux)

I wish to boot into a terminal (like pressing Control + Alt + F1) by default, but also have the GUI (Gnome, in my case) loading in the background if possible (for quick access with Control + Alt + F7).
How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, by empirical evidence, the GUI won't even start up properly unless I'm switched to it (VT7) during the loading, so I tried something else.

I used [this](http://linux.koolsolutions.com/2009/04/30/autologin-linux-console-mode/) to get *tty1* and *tty2* to autologin into my account.
Then I set up the file `~/.bash_profile` with this code:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $(tty) = 'dev/tty1' ]
then
    echo "boot script yada yada on tty1"
else
    echo "Type 'startx' to get your GUI!"
fi
```

Then I instructed the other potential users of my netbook to press Control + Alt + F2 and Control + Alt + F7 to get around. (Taped sticky note...)

This is the best solution I've found so far.
If anyone posts a better (full) solution, it'll get all the cookies.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start `Xorg` with the `-novtswitch` option. If you're using lightdm as your display manager (which is a reasonable choice), edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`, uncomment the `xserver-command` line in the `[SeatDefaults]` section and change it to

```
xserver-command=X -novtswitch
```

Set up autologin or not as desired.

---

This seems like a strange setup. There's no advantage to using the console if you're going to start an X server anyway. You might as well start the X server and open a terminal window, it'll be more comfortable at no extra cost.

Comment: I need a fullscreen terminal for my client app, and the GUI so my mother will not dissect me for not being able to watch her shows or read her recipes online. **Edit**: Also, I have no clue what "lightdm" is and the folder you mentioned doesn't exist. I use Gnome for the desktop, if it matters.

Comment: I think X11 is my display manager. `/etc/X11` contains a file named `default-display-manager`. And the Debian wiki suggests the same: https://wiki.debian.org/DisplayManager

Comment: @Vercas The display manager is the GUI program where you type your password. X11 is not a display manager. The display manager is the program mentioned in the file `/etc/X11/default-display-manager`.

Comment: It contains `/usr/sbin/gdm3`.

Comment: @Vercas It seems that [Gdm3 doesn't allow customizing how the X server is executed](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81096/how-to-make-gdm3-start-x-installed-in-a-different-path-or-running-x-from-a-pers).

Comment: So, does this mean that I can't do specifically what I want (loading GUI in background) or that I couldn't even possibly stop the GUI from loading?

Comment: @Vercas With gdm, not easily. But you could switch to lightdm. For most users, the difference in functionality between lightdm, gdm and kdm isn't noticeable.

Comment: Switched to lightdm (double checked too) and changed command as you indicated. No effect. Also, in the replacement you indicated you removed the initial `x` (xcommand -> command). Is that on purpose?

Comment: @Vercas That was a typo, it should be `xserver-command`. Does it work that way? (You need to restart lightdm for the change to take effect: `service restart lightdm`)

Comment: I restarted the laptop. I hope that's okay. When I try to restart the service, it says the service is not recognized. However, when I do `sudo service --status-all` I see ` [ + ]  lightdm`.

Comment: Also, I tried it *with* the `x` before. As stated, no changes whatsoever. :(

Comment: I've actually made huge progresses... I got ONE step left...